# Going back to prompt without ctrl c or killing process

Tags: bash, shell

In bash, I am looking for a way to go back to the prompt without waiting for command to finish.

Bearing in mind that at the time of running command, i don't know that it will take ages, so using ampersand would not be an option at that point.

Ideally the command could continue while i goto do other things in same shell

Comment: That has many answers, start command with nohup signal or via CTRL+Z pass to background, then with "bg" command switch to background or using 'screens', etc... Check [post on unix exchange](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/103731/run-a-command-without-making-me-wait)

Comment: `tmux` or `screen` is another way to deal with this. You open the application in a subshell.